# String and dots filling

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

Write a program (without using loops) which given a string, of size less
than 5, and a positive integer less than 100, prints both of them with
enough dots in between so that the whole string has 20 characters in them.

I know that if I am not using loops I have to use print(..., sep="") supresses the blank between the objects ,printed.

Can somebody tell me How do I restrict new string length to 20 characters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you need to know the length of the string and the number of digits in your integer, subtract those from 20, and you know how many dots to place in-between. This shouldn't be too hard (check out the `len()` and `str()` functions).

Did you know that you can get a string of `n` dots by doing `'.' * n`?